# OCO SELL MAX PYTHON BINANCE

Tags: python, python-3.x, binance

I can't find a way to place an OCO sell order with 100% quantity, I am trying this, but I get a MIN_NOTATIONAL error. In this case balance = 5, so I don't need to round the quantity.

```
balance = float(client.get_asset_balance(asset='VIA', recvWindow=10000)['free'])  
orderooco = client.create_oco_order(
    symbol = 'VIABTC',
    side = 'SELL',
    price = '0.00001770',
    quantity = balance,
    stopPrice = '0.00001745',
    stopLimitPrice = '0.00001740',
    stopLimitTimeInForce = 'GTC'
)
```

I also try with this

```
    def sellAmount(coin):
    balanceSell = float(client.get_asset_balance(coin,
    recvWindow=10000)['free'])
    maxSell = round(balanceSell * .995, 5)
    return balanceSell


orderooco = client.create_oco_order(
    symbol = 'VIABTC',
    side = 'SELL',
    price = '0.00001770',
    quantity = sellAmount('VIA'),
    stopPrice = '0.00001745',
    stopLimitPrice = '0.00001740',
    stopLimitTimeInForce = 'GTC'
)
```

MIN_NOTATIONAL is the error too

Answer (score 0):

> MIN_NOTATIONAL = minimum national

You can try this to check your national min with :

```
symbol_info = client.get_symbol_info("BTCUSDT")
for f in symbol_info['filters']:
    if f['filterType'] == 'MIN_NOTIONAL':
        min_notional = float(f['minNotional'])
        break
print(f"My MIN_NOTIONAL for symbole BBTCUSDT is {min_notional:.4f} BUSD")
```

This will tell you the amount minimum to trade, for France for exemple it return '10.00'